# Connection with informix database working in local but not working when website hosted on server

Tags: asp.net, database-connection, informix

I have website developed in vs2012 and a connection to informix database. The database is installed in remote server and i have credentials to connect to it, though limited access rights.
The problem is, everything is working great, when i run the project in my local pc, but when i upload the same code on remote server, its not working.

This is my web config.

```
<connectionStrings>

    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=abc\SQLServer2008;Database=bdname;User ID=un;Password=pw;" />
    <add name="TrackingDBConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=abc\SQLServer2008;Database=Tracking;User ID=un;Password=pw;Connect Timeout=200; pooling=true; Max Pool Size=200" />

  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>


    <add key="ConnMembers" value="Host=host;Server=server;Service=123;Protocol=onsoctcp;Database=dbnm;Uid=un;Pwd=pw;" />
    <add key="ConnClaims" value="Host=host;Server=server;Service=123;Protocol=onsoctcp;Database=dbnm;Uid=un;Pwd=pw;" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

Don't know how to approach.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On client machine you probably have installed Informix client. Configure remote server with  `SetNet32` (part of Informix client). There is also ODBC driver. Configure ODBC connection to remote server and check if it works.